# modify the parameter value in PortletRequest in java

Tags: spring-portlet-mvc

I am using "javax.portlet.PortletRequest" and able to get the values from the portal request using

request.getParameter("test").

I want to change values in the request object based on some conditions and pass it to some other functions.

request.setParameter("test", "abcd").

please help me out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't modify the `Parameters` on the `PortletRequest` Object. Also I suspect the existence of such `setter` method for parameter.

You can use `request.setAttribute()` to pass parameters via request Object. As you are using `Spring MVC`, you can make use of `Model` to pass/hold the **Objects** throughout the lifetime of the request.